# Как узнать коэффициенты кусочно-линейной функции при апроксимации выборки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Есть выборка данных. По ней необходимо найти коэффициенты полинома 3-й степени и кусочно-линейную функцию. Полином я нашёл очень просто с помощью функций `np.polyfit` и `np.poly1d`. Удалось построить, и график, и получить конкретное уравнение. Теперь то же самое хотелось бы сделать и для получения коэффициентов нескольких линейных функций. Мне удалось найти пример кода, который построил график, но вывести уравнения для трёх прямых не получается. Я конечно же могу посчитать их вручную, но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли штатный метод для решения данной задачи?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize

np.random.seed(9999)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) * 10
y = np.where(x < -15, -2 * x + 3, np.where(x < 10, x +
                                          48, -4 * x + 98)) + np.random.normal(0, 3, 1000)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=5, color=u'b', marker='.', label='scatter plt')


def piecewise_linear(x, x0, x1, b, k1, k2, k3):
   condlist = [x < x0, (x >= x0) & (x < x1), x >= x1]
   funclist = [lambda x: k1*x + b, lambda x: k1*x + b + k2 *
               (x-x0), lambda x: k1*x + b + k2*(x-x0) + k3*(x - x1)]
   return np.piecewise(x, condlist, funclist)


p, e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise_linear, x, y)
xd = np.linspace(-30, 30, 1000)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(xd, piecewise_linear(xd, *p))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ещё есть идея вручную разбить выборку на определённые участки и для каждого участка построить полином первой степени, но всё таки хотелось бы узнать вдруг есть готовая функция для этого

Comment: scipy.interpolate.spline пробовали? Кусочно-линейная функция это и есть сплайн первой степени.

Comment: @AlexAlex Вроде бы то что надо, но всё равно не могу получить уравнение построенной функции. И хотелось узнать, можно как-нибудь задавать количество линейных функций, которые необходимо построить. Например, для моих данных мне нужно, чтобы построилось не более трёх линейных функций.